# Is there a good way to backup Core Data database with iCloud integration?

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud

Is there a good way to backup my sqlite information from iCloud in case CoreData sqlite + iCloud corrupts? Copying the .sqlite to another location? When the iCloud corrupts, reading the data out from the .sqlite to create a new iCloud sqlite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use migratePersistentStore API to create a copy of the store file in the devices /Documents directory where it will get backed up.  See here for a more complete explanation and a sample app.

http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/sample-library-style-ios-core-data-app-with-icloud-integration/